# ¿Un DAO puede ser llamado por un Repository?

Tags: model, diseño-de-clases, ingenieria-del-software

Buscando y leyendo información acerca de las principales diferencias de un DAO y un Repositorio un DAO esta basado en una tabla en la base de datos y un Repository devuelve algo que en capas superiores es entendido(bussiness object) segun este post:
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31305199/repository-pattern-how-to-understand-it-and-how-does-it-work-with-complex-en

Ahora bien, supongamos que tenemos un Objeto que adentro tiene 4 objetos mas cada uno de diferentes tablas , seria valido que un repositorio llamara a 4 daos para componer un objeto así?, no creo que los 4 daos se manden a llamar a la capa de servicio para componer un objeto complejo, todo esto nace a partir de que he visto en muchos libros las 3 típicas capas de una aplicación:

Controller -> Service -> Repository
ó
Controller -> Service -> DAO

En si es solo una gran duda si un repository puede llamar a daos para componer un objeto mas complejo.

Un ejemplo de metodo en el repository seria asi:

```
public Cliente obtenerCliente(int idCliente){
    InformacionCliente informacionCliente = 
    daoInformacionCliente.obtenerDatosCliente(idCliente);
    Cuenta cuenta = daoCuenta.obtenerCuenta(idCliente);
    HistoricoCliente historico = daoHistoricoCliente.obtenerHistorialCliente(idCliente);
    Cliente cliente = new Cliente();
    c.setInformacionCliente(informacionCliente);
    c.setCuenta(cuenta);
    c.setHistorial(historico);
    return cliente;
}
```

Casi no se mucho de arquitecturas actualmente estoy leyendo varios libros de DDD diseño guiado por el dominio pero lejos de aclararme unas cosas me salen mas dudas, de antemano muchísimas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Respondiendo a tus preguntas: 
*"Supongamos que tenemos un Objeto que adentro tiene 4 objetos mas cada uno de diferentes tablas, ¿seria valido que un repositorio llamara a 4 daos para componer un objeto asi?"*

Habría que identificar que tecnologías o de que manera implementas tu DAO, pero si por ejemplo utilizas JPA que es una de las opciones más utilizadas actualmente (Spring, Hibernate), la manera más cómoda es seguir los estándares de JPA.

Es decir, para recuperar por ejemplo una `"Persona"` tenemos que recuperar también su `"Empresa"`, `"Coche"`, `"Direcciones"`. Para el caso del DAO de `"Persona"` por defecto este recuperará de manera automática todos los elementos, incluidos los objetos "Empresa", "Coche", "Direcciones" que pertenecen a diferentes tablas en BBDD. Pero para el caso concreto de "Direcciones" como es un listado, en dependencia de que implementación de JPA utilicies, lo normal es que sea Lazy (no se trae el listado hasta que tu no lo necesitas).

Respecto a la arquitectura de este tipo de situaciones, lo normal es que sea suficiente con CONTROLADOR -> SERVICIO -> DAO. Donde servicio es el que tiene la capacidad de llamar a varios DAOs.

De manera que al controlador le llegarán peticiones (de la vista por ejemplo) del tipo dame todas las `"Nominas"` de las `"Personas"` que pertenezcan a la `"Empresa"` X. Es aquí donde el Controlador debe distinguir que tiene que devolver un listado de nominas, por lo que se llama al Servicio de Nominas (ej: `obtenerNominaParaEmpresa(Empresa e)`), este realizará la consulta que le corresponde (Todas las personas de la Empresa X) llamando al DAO de "Persona" (ej: `findAllByEmpresa(Empresa e)`), pero luego realizará una nueva búsqueda, llamando al DAO de "Nomina" (ej: `findOneByPersona(Persona p)`), indicando que quiere la nomina correspondiente a esa persona (Suponiendo que PERSONA NO CONOCE NOMINA).

Esta sería la manera más simple de mantener una estructura mantenible y reutilizable.

Para tu ejemplo de repositirio yo lo vería de la siguiente manera, desde la vista se da click en ver información de cliente.

Se llama directamente al CONTROLADOR para gestionar dicha solicitud (obtenerCliente), y este se encargará de gestionar dicha solicitud:

CONTROLADOR:

```
public Cliente obtenerCliente(int idCliente){
//Validaciones, cambios de estados en la vista.. y más logíca
return servicioCliente.obtenerCliente(idCliente);
}
```

SERVICIO:

```
public Cliente obtenerCliente(int idCliente){
InformacionCliente informacionCliente = daoInformacionCliente.obtenerDatosCliente(idCliente);
    Cuenta cuenta = daoCuenta.obtenerCuenta(idCliente);
    HistoricoCliente historico = daoHistoricoCliente.obtenerHistorialCliente(idCliente);
    Cliente cliente = new Cliente();
    c.setInformacionCliente(informacionCliente);
    c.setCuenta(cuenta);
    c.setHistorial(historico);
    return cliente;
}
```

Espero que te sea de utilidad.